# Drupal 7 to 9 migration fails with 'missing migrations' errors using UI

Tags: drupal, migration, drupal-7, drupal-9

I am trying to migrate a Drupal 7 site to Drupal 9 using the Migrate Drupal UI. I have read through and followed the corresponding tutorials on drupal.org but migration fails.

Given that my original Drupal 7 site is quite complex, for testing purposes, I created a fresh installation of Drupal 7 and created some dummy content of the content type Article, then I ran the upgrade from the user interface in Drupal 9.

The *What will be upgraded?* page indicated that 29 modules would be upgraded (including Node). After performing the upgrade, I got the following messages:

> Completed 39 upgrade tasks successfully

> 40 upgrades failed

> Upgrade process not completed

The content hadn't been migrated.

When I checked the upgrade log, I found the following error:

> Migration d7_node:article did not meet the requirements. Missing migrations d7_node_type, d7_user. requirements: d7_node_type. requirements: d7_user.

The *d7_node_type.yml* and *d7_user.yml migration* files are there in the appropriate Drupal 9 folders, so I don't understand what the problem is. What am I missing?

Comment: I have the same issue with upgrading from d7 to d9... did you solve it in the end?